# How enabled Network Provider in android?

Tags: android, android-location

when i debug my code with device(sony Xperia)  for getting Latitude and Longitude using WIFI show false status for network provider.WIFI connection is on and all required permission i added to mainfeast.xml file.

it show me null to this method.

```
NetworkProvider=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

And show null value for location when Network Provider Is Enabled.

```
locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_Provider);
```

i added these permission.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

How may i fix this problem.

My Code is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
context=getApplicationContext();
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
    status12=checkStatus();
    if(status12)
    {
        addListenerAction();
    }
    }
});
}

public boolean checkStatus()
{
locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
provider1=locationManager.getProviders(true);
for(String s : provider1)
{
    if(s.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    {
    gpsStatus=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(gpsStatus)
    {
        status=true;
    }
    }
    if(s.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
    {
    NetworkProvider=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(NetworkProvider)
    {
        status=true;
    }
    }
    if(s.equals(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER))
    {
    PassiveProvider=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

    if(PassiveProvider)
    {
        status=true;
    }
    }
}
return status;
}

private class Abcd implements LocationListener
{
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{
    if(loc !=null)
    {
    if(gpsStatus)
    {

        latitude=loc.getLatitude();
        longitude=loc.getLongitude();
        System.out.println("Longitude ="+longitude);
        System.out.println("Latitude ="+latitude);

        try
        {
        geocoder = new Geocoder(context,Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println("GeoCoder ="+geocoder);
        address=geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);
        System.out.println("Address ="+address);
        if(!address.isEmpty())
        {
            Cityname=address.get(0).getLocality();
            country = address.get(0).getCountryName();
            Address=address.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            System.out.println("Country Name ="+country);
            System.out.println("CityName ="+Cityname);
            System.out.println("Address ="+Address);
            ShowLocation sw=new ShowLocation();

        }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(NetworkProvider)
    {
        latitude=loc.getLatitude();
        longitude=loc.getLongitude();
        System.out.println("Longitude ="+longitude);
        System.out.println("Latitude ="+latitude);

        try
        {
        geocoder = new Geocoder(context,Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println("GeoCoder ="+geocoder);
        address=geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);
        System.out.println("Address ="+address);
        if(!address.isEmpty())
        {
            Cityname=address.get(0).getLocality();
            country = address.get(0).getCountryName();
            Address=address.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            System.out.println("Country Name ="+country);
            System.out.println("CityName ="+Cityname);
            System.out.println("Address ="+Address);
            ShowLocation sw=new ShowLocation();

        }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(PassiveProvider)
    {
        latitude=loc.getLatitude();
        longitude=loc.getLongitude();
        System.out.println("Longitude ="+longitude);
        System.out.println("Latitude ="+latitude);

        try
        {
        geocoder = new Geocoder(context,Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println("GeoCoder ="+geocoder);
        address=geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);
        System.out.println("Address ="+address);
        if(!address.isEmpty())
        {
            Cityname=address.get(0).getLocality();
            country = address.get(0).getCountryName();
            Address=address.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            System.out.println("Country Name ="+country);
            System.out.println("CityName ="+Cityname);
            System.out.println("Address ="+Address);
            ShowLocation sw=new ShowLocation();

        }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    }
}
@Override   
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
    Bundle extras) {
}
}

public void addListenerAction()
{
locationListener=new Abcd(); 
if(gpsStatus)
{
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,time,distance, locationListener);
    Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
    provider=locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    System.out.println("Location ="+location);
    locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
}
if(NetworkProvider)
{
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,time,distance, locationListener);
    Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
    provider=locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
}
if(PassiveProvider)
{
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER,time,distance, locationListener);
    Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
    provider=locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
}
}
```

Comment: i am getting value form Gps Provider but want access through Passive or network provider.

Comment: did you initialize locationmanager?

Comment: ya i initialized with setSystemServices(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) methode

Comment: when i run my code with Gps it provide me Longitude and latitude but when i turn on wifi of device it provides me only passive provider

Comment: and passive provider it does not allow location

Comment: why i can't understand

Comment: because my passive provider is enabled of deviced

Comment: and my network provider status is always false but my WIfi of my device is on

Comment: locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(mContext.LOCATION_SERVICE);  use this code for initialize locationmanager

Comment: i already used this methode

Comment: can you post your full code snippet?

Comment: show i will edit the code

Comment: Ok please edit your code

Comment: i have added my code with this question

Comment: i checked your code for me it is working fine. in my device all provider's status is coming "true"

Comment: for network provider its true

Comment: and for Passive Provider is Working

Comment: i am getting all provider's status true

Comment: Miss. Shweta tell me one thing more please

Comment: and i check that code after WiFi off also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51487/discussion-between-shweta-jain-and-user3509581)

Answer (score 2):

use this code for initialize locationmanager

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(mContext.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```